How to solve error "delayed connect error: 111"
I have deployed my Laravel project on google cloud. I've created VM, load balancer and also implemented CDN.
First, I've created load balancer without https and at that time everything was working fine on load balancer's IP.
Then I https and created https certificate and also updated name servers from the DNS records on the domain name.
Now website looks fine. But when I submit any form means try to do POST method then it shows error:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111

Get method works fine.
Check attached screenshot of ajax call request using post method.
enter image description here
enter image description here
How can I solve this. Thanks in advance!
